# Converting XX-HH:MM:SS to timedelta

Tags: python

I have a column with values that look like this:

```
99920387    40-11:23:15
99920388          00:00
99920389          00:00
99920390          00:00
99920391          00:00
99920392    31-20:29:07
99920393       20:17:05
99920394       20:17:05
99920395    28-10:09:59
99920396    28-10:09:59
99920397          44:16
99920398          29:08
99920399          29:05
99920400          20:44
```

I would like to convert them to a timedelta format, but when I do `pd.to_timedelta(df['ELAPSED']`, I get a **ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format**

UPDATE:
When I read in the first hundred columns, I am able to successfully convert it using `pd.to_timedelta(df['ELAPSED']`, because the first hundred columns are in the same format:

```
0     79-10:14:49
1     79-10:14:49
2     79-10:14:49
3     79-10:14:49
4     79-10:14:49
5     79-10:14:49
6     79-10:14:49
7     79-10:14:49
```

This is what it looks like when it works (for the first 100 rows):

```
0    -330 days +09:45:11
1    -330 days +09:45:11
2    -330 days +09:45:11
3    -330 days +09:45:11
4    -330 days +09:45:11
5    -330 days +09:45:11
6    -330 days +09:45:11
7    -330 days +09:45:11
```

However, when I read in the rest of the data and the formats range from XX-HH:MM:SS to MM:SS, it breaks. My questions are 1) What is a good solution for handling this kind of inconsistently formatted data? And 2) How is **79-10:14:49** converted to **-330 days +09:45:11**?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that makes sense because it's quite hard to tell what the format is for your 'Elapsed' column. 28-10:09:59 - Is this 28 days 10 hours 9 minutes and 59 seconds? You probably have to convert the days to hours, judging from the error output

Comment: I'm not surprised that `pandas` is confused, because so am I :). What does `40-11:23:15` mean? Or specifically, what does the `40-` part mean?

Comment: You need to understand what the 'dd-' prefix means first before even trying to convert